# How to decode json in php to insert into database

Tags: php, json

My json data look like:-

{"_id":{"$oid":"56f7691531cd90e6117b375b"},"user":{"$oid":"56f7691131cd90e6117b375a"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"56f8954771af9a655f73aa31"},"user":{"$oid":"56f8954671af9a655f73aa30"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"56fac95cc0ba33890825e89b"},"user":{"$oid":"56fac95bc0ba33890825e89a"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"56facb44c0ba33890825e8a0"},"user":{"$oid":"56facb44c0ba33890825e89f"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"56fad24553620b8f0cd4e520"},"user":{"$oid":"56fad24553620b8f0cd4e51f"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"56fc161cbd67182d0fa84131"},"user":{"$oid":"56fc161cbd67182d0fa84130"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"56fe839fbd67182d0fa84153"},"user":{"$oid":"56fe839fbd67182d0fa84152"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"570baf411560f443514d247e"},"user":{"$oid":"570baf401560f443514d247d"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"571a30c93a11a56244a5d2aa"},"user":{"$oid":"571a30c93a11a56244a5d2a9"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"571a36183a11a56244a5d2b7"},"user":{"$oid":"571a36183a11a56244a5d2b6"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"571a39393a11a56244a5d2b9"},"user":{"$oid":"571a39393a11a56244a5d2b8"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"571a45cf3a11a56244a5d2bb"},"user":{"$oid":"571a45cf3a11a56244a5d2ba"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"571a499a3a11a56244a5d2c9"},"user":{"$oid":"571a499a3a11a56244a5d2c8"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"571a64f60f97b4d16c188430"},"user":{"$oid":"571a64f60f97b4d16c18842f"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"5722ecb29787b9a651b727dd"},"user":{"$oid":"5722ecb19787b9a651b727dc"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"57265da014d49e6a6e4c8e20"},"user":{"$oid":"57265da014d49e6a6e4c8e1f"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"572755eb14d49e6a6e4c8e3b"},"user":{"$oid":"572755eb14d49e6a6e4c8e3a"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"57276d7d14d49e6a6e4c8e5a"},"user":{"$oid":"57276d7c14d49e6a6e4c8e59"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"572cf992ecbaa8224a72a0ce"},"user":{"$oid":"572cf992ecbaa8224a72a0cd"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"573a14c81e46221540ff8479"},"user":{"$oid":"573a14c81e46221540ff8478"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"573f0c7c7f91fcb3274af867"},"user":{"$oid":"573f0c7c7f91fcb3274af866"},"__v":0} {"_id":{"$oid":"577760853858cf573d2928f7"},"user":{"$oid":"577760853858cf573d2928f6"},"__v":0}

Comment: With json_docode($yourJson) : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @Knriano thanx dear but its not working.. :(

Comment: Are you trying to decode all of your json at the same time? If yes, that won't work because it's not a valid json but if you do it line by line you shoudn't have a problem.

Comment: ok @Knriano, thanx i'll try :)

Comment: [one way to convert it to valid json and then into a PHP array](https://eval.in/610434)

Comment: Thank you soo much @Ryan Vincent, it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that each of those lines of code are a separate line of json code being returned. If so, you can use json_decode like so:

```
<?php
    $json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

    var_dump(json_decode($json)); //returns an object
    var_dump(json_decode($json, true));  //returns an array

?>
```

Comment: thanks @pogeybait but its not working... :) it returns NULL

Comment: json_decode return NULL in case of if pass invalid json object or array.First you check your json is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data is little bit strange, there is not enough commas after the braces. If you will try this example to decode, than it will works:

```
$json = '[
    {"_id":{"$oid":"56f7691531cd90e6117b375b"},"user":{"$oid":"56f7691131cd90e6117b375a"},"__v":0},
    {"_id":{"$oid":"56f8954771af9a655f73aa31"},"user":{"$oid":"56f8954671af9a655f73aa30"},"__v":0},
    {"_id":{"$oid":"56fac95cc0ba33890825e89b"},"user":{"$oid":"56fac95bc0ba33890825e89a"},"__v":0},
    {"_id":{"$oid":"56facb44c0ba33890825e8a0"},"user":{"$oid":"56facb44c0ba33890825e89f"},"__v":0} 
]';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```